# Get an ordered list of imported modules in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

Is there a way to get a list of imported modules that are listed as imported?

`globals()` returns  a dict which is unordered.

Comment: Do you mean ordered by "how they were imported" (name) or by the "order in which they were imported" (time-like) or something else entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's not guaranteed that the dictionary is ordered in CPython-3.6 **it is ordered** in the current 3.6 versions of CPython.

So if you display `sys.modules` (a dictionary containing all loaded modules) it should be ordered by the "relative order of imports":

```
import sys

print(list(sys.modules))
```